# How to display current html page with js onclick?

Tags: javascript, html

I am currently trying to implement the page layout change with js onclick of the function, and the question is, how do I make the js display the current body html?

The logic is as following:

first I have my page html and the body dom, then I have the script where I define that if you click on the button then you have different content displayed, using the `pageLayout.innerHTML = "<p>this is the new content</p>"`.

But how do I make the js display back the last content, or be back to the content that is defined on top of the script in the body without copy pasting it twice in the end with the same function?

Comment: put new content(s) in an array, then use last item in array for the innerHTML, this way you got a history, you only need to figure out how to traverse the array to pick out a specific item, or first item etc, which would be trivial

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can store the previous content in a global variable, before making any changes.

So if you want the same button to revert the content you can do something like this:

```
let previousContent = "";

function handleClick() {
  // Find the element that you want to change its content
  const pageLayout = document.getElementById("layout");

  // Check if there is any stored content
  if(previousContent) {
    pageLayout.innerHTML = previousContent;
    
    //Clear the stored content
    previousContent = "";

  } else {

    // Store the previous content
    previousContent = pageLayout.innerHTML;

    //Create the new content
    const newContent = " your new content";

    //Update the content
    pageLayout.innerHTML = newContent;

  }
}

const button = document.getElementById("my-button-id");
button.addEventListener("click", handleClick);
```